# 1-D interpolation using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation

I have a data that looks like a sigmoidal plot but flipped relative to the vertical line. [image]

But the plot is a result of plotting 1D data instead of some sort of function.

My goal is to find the x value when the y value is at 50%. As you can see, there is no data point when y is exactly at 50%.
Interpolate comes to my mind. But I'm not sure if interpolate enable me to find the x value when the y value is 50%. So my question is 1) can you use interpolate to find the x when the y is 50%? or 2)do you need to fit the data to some sort of a function?

Below is what I currently have in my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


my_x = [4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66]

my_y_raw=np.array([0.99470977497817203, 0.99434995886145172, 0.98974611323163653, 0.961630837657524, 0.99327633558441175, 0.99338952769251909, 0.99428263292577534, 0.98690514212711611, 0.99111667721533181, 0.99149418924880861, 0.99133773062680464, 0.99143506380003499, 0.99151080464011454, 0.99268261743308517, 0.99289757252812316, 0.99100207861144063, 0.99157171773324027, 0.99112571824824358, 0.99031608691035722, 0.98978104266076905, 0.989782674787969, 0.98897835092187614, 0.98517540405423909, 0.98308943666187076, 0.96081810781994603, 0.85563541881892147, 0.61570811548079107, 0.33076276040577052, 0.14655134838124245, 0.076853147122142126, 0.035831324928136087, 0.021344669212790181])
my_y=my_y_raw/np.max(my_y_raw)

plt.plot(my_x, my_y,color='k', markersize=40)
plt.scatter(my_x,my_y,marker='*',label="myplot", color='k', edgecolor='k', linewidth=1,facecolors='none',s=50)
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.xlim([4,102])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, I realized that there were some errors, but I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using SciPy

The most straightforward way to do the interpolation is to use the SciPy [interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) function. SciPy is closely related to NumPy and you may already have it installed. The advantage to `interp1d` is that it can sort the data for you. This comes at the cost of somewhat funky syntax. In many interpolation functions it is assumed that you are trying to interpolate a y value from an x value. These functions generally need the "x" values to be monotonically increasing. In your case, we swap the normal sense of x and y. The y values have an outlier as @Abhishek Mishra has pointed out. In the case of your data, you are lucky and you can get away with the the leaving the outlier in.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

my_x = [4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,
48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66]

my_y_raw=np.array([0.99470977497817203, 0.99434995886145172, 
0.98974611323163653, 0.961630837657524, 0.99327633558441175, 
0.99338952769251909, 0.99428263292577534, 0.98690514212711611, 
0.99111667721533181, 0.99149418924880861, 0.99133773062680464, 
0.99143506380003499, 0.99151080464011454, 0.99268261743308517, 
0.99289757252812316, 0.99100207861144063, 0.99157171773324027, 
0.99112571824824358, 0.99031608691035722, 0.98978104266076905, 
0.989782674787969, 0.98897835092187614, 0.98517540405423909, 
0.98308943666187076, 0.96081810781994603, 0.85563541881892147, 
0.61570811548079107, 0.33076276040577052, 0.14655134838124245, 
0.076853147122142126, 0.035831324928136087, 0.021344669212790181])

# set assume_sorted to have scipy automatically sort for you
f = interp1d(my_y_raw, my_x, assume_sorted = False)
xnew = f(0.5)

print('interpolated value is ', xnew)

plt.plot(my_x, my_y_raw,'x-', markersize=10)
plt.plot(xnew, 0.5, 'x', color = 'r', markersize=20)
plt.plot((0, xnew), (0.5,0.5), ':')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

which gives

```
interpolated value is  56.81214249272691
```

[image]

## Using NumPy

Numpy also has an [interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) function, but it doesn't do the sort for you. And if you don't sort, you'll be sorry:

> Does not check that the x-coordinate sequence xp is increasing. If xp
>   is not increasing, the results are nonsense.

The only way I could get np.interp to work was to shove the data in to a structured array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_x = np.array([4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,
48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66], dtype = np.float)


my_y_raw=np.array([0.99470977497817203, 0.99434995886145172, 
0.98974611323163653, 0.961630837657524, 0.99327633558441175, 
0.99338952769251909, 0.99428263292577534, 0.98690514212711611, 
0.99111667721533181, 0.99149418924880861, 0.99133773062680464, 
0.99143506380003499, 0.99151080464011454, 0.99268261743308517, 
0.99289757252812316, 0.99100207861144063, 0.99157171773324027, 
0.99112571824824358, 0.99031608691035722, 0.98978104266076905, 
0.989782674787969, 0.98897835092187614, 0.98517540405423909, 
0.98308943666187076, 0.96081810781994603, 0.85563541881892147, 
0.61570811548079107, 0.33076276040577052, 0.14655134838124245, 
0.076853147122142126, 0.035831324928136087, 0.021344669212790181], 
dtype = np.float)

dt = np.dtype([('x', np.float), ('y', np.float)])
data = np.zeros( (len(my_x)), dtype = dt)
data['x'] = my_x
data['y'] = my_y_raw

data.sort(order = 'y') # sort data in place by y values

print('numpy interp gives ', np.interp(0.5, data['y'], data['x']))
```

which gives

```
numpy interp gives  56.81214249272691
```

Comment: Hi @bfris, thanks for your answer. The code works! I have one additional question. So I used the scipy to do the interpolation since I don't need to sort the data manually. One question I had was that I want to visualize/plot the interpolated points and see how well the points generated from interpolation agrees with my given data. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @bfris, thanks for your comment. I kinda figured out xnew = f(0.5) gives x value when y is 0.5. But I was curious where how I can call for a list of y values generated from interpolation so that I could plot y values that can show all the y values generated from interpolation.

Comment: the scipy function will happily take an array of values. So instead of `xnew = f(0.5)`, you could have `ynew = np.linspace(0.025, 0.99, 10)` and `xnew = f(ynew)`

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your data looks like a flipped sigmoidal. Can we make the assumption that your function is a strictly decreasing function? If that is the case, we can try the following methods:

1. Remove all the points where the data is not strictly decreasing.For example, for your data that point will be near 0.
2. Use the binary search to find the location where y=0.5 should be put in.
3. Now you know two (x, y) pairs where your desired y=0.5 should lie.
4. You can use simple linear interpolation if (x, y) pairs are very close.
5. Otherwise, you can see what is the approximation of sigmoid near those pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to fit any functions to your data. Simply find the following two elements:

1. The largest x for which y<50%
2. The smallest x for which y>50%

Then use interpolation and find the x*. Below is the code

```
my_x = np.array([4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66])
my_y=np.array([0.99470977497817203, 0.99434995886145172, 0.98974611323163653, 0.961630837657524, 0.99327633558441175, 0.99338952769251909, 0.99428263292577534, 0.98690514212711611, 0.99111667721533181, 0.99149418924880861, 0.99133773062680464, 0.99143506380003499, 0.99151080464011454, 0.99268261743308517, 0.99289757252812316, 0.99100207861144063, 0.99157171773324027, 0.99112571824824358, 0.99031608691035722, 0.98978104266076905, 0.989782674787969, 0.98897835092187614, 0.98517540405423909, 0.98308943666187076, 0.96081810781994603, 0.85563541881892147, 0.61570811548079107, 0.33076276040577052, 0.14655134838124245, 0.076853147122142126, 0.035831324928136087, 0.021344669212790181])

tempInd1 = my_y<.5 # This will only work if the values are monotonic

x1 = my_x[tempInd1][0]
y1 = my_y[tempInd1][0]

x2 = my_x[~tempInd1][-1]
y2 = my_y[~tempInd1][-1]

scipy.interp(0.5, [y1, y2], [x1, x2])
```

Comment: Okay. can you describe in more details?

Comment: I added a code in my answer. Run it and let me know if it makes sense. Best, Gobrays.